# why module in not found in angular "TestBed"?

Tags: javascript, angular

could you please tell me why why module in not found in angular  ?
here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/8k7vlvl5q2

issue is on this line

```
<<import { ComponentFixture, async, TestBed } from "@angular/testing";
>>
```

`TestBed` is not found

[image]

Comment: Maybe see https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/16867

Comment: but the bug is closed

Answer (score 0):

There is no module named `@angular/testing`.

You have to import `TestBed` from `@angular/core/testing`.

Change your import line to

`import { ComponentFixture, async, TestBed } from "@angular/core/testing";`

Also make sure you install `@angular/core` correctly.